# Confusing overload resolution failure regarding number of type arguments

Tags: vb.net, generics, overload-resolution

In C#, I can write:

```cs
Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select(i => i)
```

And I can also specify the two type parameters to `Select` explicitly:

```cs
Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select<int, int>(i => i)
```

In VB, the equivalent of the first snippet works fine:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select(Function(i) i)
```

But when I try to specify the type parameters, it fails:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select(Of Integer, Integer)(Function(i) i)
```

The error I'm getting is:

> BC32087   Overload resolution failed because no accessible '[Select]' accepts this number of type arguments.

I don't understand: there is [an overload of extension method named `Select` with two type parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Give this a try :

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select(Of Integer)(Function(i) i)
```

The reason that your previous example wasn't working was because [the overload that you referenced](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891) was actually an extension method for `Enumerable` objects and thus the first parameter is actually the object that is triggering the call.

You can [see an example of this being used here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kY6Uvh) and working as expected.